# how to display occurrence of specific word in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie to mysql PHP. I want to count the occurrence of a specific word in a MySQL db row. For example: There are two columns name and jobsataus.

| id | name | job_status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | umar | done | 2022-09-22 |
| 2 | umar | done | 2022-09-22 |
| 3 | umar | done | 2022-09-22 |
| 4 | umar | rebook | 2022-09-22 |
| 5 | umar | rebook | 2022-09-22 |
| 6 | umar | done | 2022-09-22 |
| 7 | umar | rebook | 2022-09-22 |
| 8 | umar | done | 2022-09-23 |
| 9 | umar | rebook | 2022-09-23 |
| 10 | umar | rebook | 2022-09-23 |
| 11 | umar | Three | 2022-09-23 |
| 12 | umar | cancelled | 2022-09-23 |
| 13 | umar | done | 2022-09-23 |
| 14 | umar | cancelled | 2022-09-23 |
| 15 | khan | cancelled | 2022-09-24 |
| 16 | khan | rebook | 2022-09-24 |
| 17 | khan | cancelled | 2022-09-24 |
| 18 | khan | rebook | 2022-09-24 |
| 19 | khan | done | 2022-09-24 |
| 20 | khan | rebook | 2022-09-24 |
| 21 | khan | done | 2022-09-24 |

I want to count the occurrence of the word 'done,rebook,cancelled' from the  row job_status column.pls guide me

I want this output:
| date| name | totaldone|totalrebook|totalcancelled|
|:---- |:------:| -----:| -----:| -----:|
| 2022-09-22| umar| 4 |3 |0|
| 2022-09-23  | umar| 0|1|2|
| 2022-09-24| umar| 2|0|0|

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow bobs! please take a [tour] and learn [ask]. it would be best to write a [mcve] so we can help you better. also, we'd like to know what you have tried. happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUPING and subqueries.

```
SELECT `date`, `name`,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `specific` WHERE `job_status`='done' AND `name`=s1.`name`) AS total_done,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `specific` WHERE `job_status`='rebook' AND `name`=s1.`name`) AS total_rebook,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `specific` WHERE `job_status`='cancelled' AND `name`=s1.`name`) AS total_cancelled
FROM `specific` AS s1 WHERE 1 GROUP BY `name`
```

#### Output

| date | name | total_done | total_rebook | total_cancelled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-22 | umar | 6 | 5 | 2 |
| 2022-09-24 | khan | 2 | 3 | 2 |

Comment: when i tried this qurey error display on my myql 
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Then you have a server / neworking problem. Or do you have millions of records and no index in the name and job_status? The query works. See https://ibb.co/ZzGBv3h